# How to find out maximum EGL current contexts?

Tags: android, opengl-es, egl

Egl documentation states:

> If binding context would exceed the number of current contexts of that client API type supported by the implementation, an EGL_BAD_ACCESS error is generated.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglMakeCurrent.xhtml

So is there any way to query "number of current contexts of that client API type supported"?

or is it provided by graphic vendors manually? (e.g driver specification)

Comment: I have found that on a Google Pixel 2 running Android 10 I am able to create 32 `EGLContext` objects and then on the 33rd `eglCreateContext` fails with error `EGL_BAD_ALLOC`. On a Samsung Galaxy S10+ I was able to far exceed this number with at least 512 `EGLContext` objects, so it seems device specific but I was unable to find any way of finding the limit.